# AS3 - Get Google Analytics status

Tags: actionscript-3, google-analytics, tracking

I'm using Google Analytics for Flash. How to find out if the tracker is working?

This is the code:

```
import com.google.analytics.GATracker;
import com.google.analytics.AnalyticsTracker;

var tracker:AnalyticsTracker;
tracker = new GATracker(this, "UA-123456789-1", "AS3", false);
```

This comes up in the GA debug mode:

> User is online: Gif Request #0 failed
>
> User is offline: Gif Request #0 sent

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same problem today. I found  [explanation from google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingIntro?hl=ru-RU#troubleshooting): Currently, Flash tracking is available for any Flash content embedded in a web page. Tracking of data sent from Adobe Air, Shockwave, or via the Flash IDE (e.g. using Test Movie) is not supported at this time.

I suppose only way to track data from flash with google analytics - use bridge method (ga.js). Or use other analytics site, like  [appanalytics](http://www.appanalyticshq.com/) .